# search value between 2 datetime in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

In winform app i have a datagridview for showing the database values. i use these following codes to see the result between two specific datetime for example between 6/5/2010 and 7/5/2010 but it just show me the rows which exactly updated in these datetime. i mean it just show me the rows which has exact Registrationday and finish day. i want to see all the results between these times.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sql = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-PC\PC;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select EntryID,Name,FamilyName,Registrationday,Finishday,Fee from Entry where Registrationday =@Registrationday AND Finishday =@Finishday", sql);
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Signday", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text).ToShortDateString());
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finishday", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text).ToShortDateString());
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rows *overlapping* your interval:

```
Registrationday <= @Finishday AND Finishday >= @Registrationday
```

This matches all the following rows:

```
-------R-------F-----------
    *------------*
     *------*
       *---*
          *---*
            *------*
```

For rows contained *entirely within* your interval:

```
Registrationday >= @Registrationday AND Finishday <= @Finishday
```

This matches only these rows:

```
-------R-------F-----------
       *---*
          *---*
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify <= and >= for range

```
 Registrationday >=@Registrationday AND Finishday <=@Finishday
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`BETWEEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187922.aspx):

```
SELECT  EntryID, Name, FamilyName, Registrationday, Finishday, Fee 
FROM    [Entry] 
where Registrationday BETWEEN @Registrationday AND  @Finishday
```

Although it is not clear why you filter on `Finishday` at all.

Note thast you should not pass a `String` as parameter but a `DateTime`

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registrationday", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text));
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Finishday", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text));
```

Comment: the problem with `BETEEN` though is it gets all moody and refuses to do it's homework...

Comment: if i don't use ToShortDateString() i needs 12.00.00 AM.

Comment: @aliprogrammer: You should use a DateTime anyway if you don't want to run into(future) globalization issues. You could simply use the [`DateTime.ToDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property:  `Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text).Date`. It's also faster to convert it to the appropriate `Type` in the first place than in the dbms.

Answer (score 1):

just update the query string

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select EntryID,Name,FamilyName,Registrationday,Finishday,Fee from Entry where Registrationday >=@Registrationday AND Finishday <=@Finishday", sql);
```